# EmbeddedViewRef.detectChanges() and ngZone: noop

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-changedetection

For educational purposes I'm trying to build a directive that updates the UI even when NgZone is deactivated. The directive accepts an observable as an input and every time it emits a new value, it is supposed to update the UI with EmbeddedViewRef.detectChanges().

You can see in the example linked below, in observe.directive.ts, in the detect function, there is a console.log proving that the state itself is updating but the UI isn't.
In order to see that the state changes but UI doesn't, try to add a new todo by typing something in the input and pressing the enter key and then open the console.

Hoping someone could explain why the UI isn't updating.

[CodeSanbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-pine-jfg4j?file=/src/app/observe.directive.ts)

Comment: if I look correctly your view is static. just hardcoded list with one item. there is nothing to update on it, although you are calling detect changes on it.

Comment: Try adding a new todo and open the console. You will see a log of the state, proving that the state is updated but the UI isn't

Comment: yeah, i see console, but your ui just contains single <li>, instead of dynamic *ngFor based on todo list

Comment: Forgot to copy the ngFor when recreating the codesandbox from my local environment, but check now...  